# GWT MouseOver performance

Tags: java, performance, internet-explorer, gwt, flextable

I'm writing an application in GWT. It went really well, until I ran it in IE.

I made an application that uses a FlexTable, and each cell of the table was to be highlighted. I wrote the MouseOver handler, but in the Internet Explorer it works incredibly slow.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: It might be worth talking a bit about what kind of logic is in the mouseover handler. We've done things like that and it has not burned us too badly, but we were basically just doing some minor rendering changes. Are you restructuring the table much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlexTable`'s performance kinda sucks in IE (BTW, which version of GWT are you using?), because of the DOM methods needed there to create the table. However, [`Grid`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Grid.html) should provide you with a nice boost in performance, *if* the size of your table is constant and known beforehand and you don't need jagged tables (otherwise you can't even use it :)).
A compromise between the two would be one of the tables from [GWT's Incubator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/) - for example [`ScrollTable`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ScrollTable) has support for mouseovers straight out of the box and [BulkTableRenderers](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/BulkTableRenderers) should speed up the creation of your table (there's even a version for `FlexTable`). Even if you are not interested in using them in production, it might be worth checking out, for example, how they implemented MouseOver events on IE.

Comment: I'm using GWT2.0, and I need to merge cells dynamically. Seems I'll have to find another solution:/ Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've decided to rewrite the widget using AbsolutePanel.